# Pivot-table for survey data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have some survey data that I have struggled with for two days, using advice on this website and others, to make the pivot table I want but have failed dismally so some advice would be appreciated.

I have a bunch of data that has already been completed via pen & paper that captures demographics such as nationality and gender, then a list of about 35 questions on morale and stress in the organisation, for about 75 respondents. (Yes, I wish they had used an electronic-based survey tool too.) Anyway, I am fine with analysing the overall data, eg what percentage strongly agree that they enjoy their work; but I want to be able to filter & show that data by nationality or gender or both; for example, what percentage of women strongly agree, agree, or disagree with a particular statement. Basically the survey includes:

*Respondent no.*

*Nationality*

*Sex*

*Questions* (choose from degrees: *Always, Very often, Often, Sometimes, Seldom, Very Seldom, Never*):

```
Q1. I get along with my colleagues; 
Q2. Information is shared at all levels; 
Q3. I feel I can trust my colleagues; 
etc, etc.
```

I have played and played with the data which is in a list with no blanks or filters; I have tried both numerical and text responses; portrait and landscape, and I have moved the four parts of the pivot table (*filters, columns, rows and values*) through various permutations but can not get the look I want (see next paragraph). Indeed if I get close to the layout I want, then the values for Q1 are repeated in every other question, or I get a list of the degress again, or some other nonsense.

Layout: Demographic filters top left, questions across the top of the columns, degrees (*Always, Very often*, etc) down the left-hand column, the count of responses by question and degree in the middle and totals at the bottom.

Any help would be appreciated!

PS, apologies for not being able to show tables of the data, what I want or how it comes out; SO won't let me upload screen shots.

[Excel pivot table that counts non-numeric data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572607/excel-pivot-table-that-counts-non-numeric-data)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Pivot Table from some mock data.  Is this what you are looking for?

[image: Pivot Table example]